# Comunication between C# and Arduino via bluetooth, receiving strange data

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino, serial-port, communication

I'm trying to send data between an Arduino Mega and a C# windows form application via Bluetooth.

From Arduino to C# all goes well, however, when sending from C# to Arduino I get some strange values:
Sending "abcde" outputs 79 167 186 170 2. I assume each one of the values represents a letter, as sending only "a" outputs 79.

However, I can't see why I get this values and not ascii ones, for example.

Here's the relevant C# code:

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
serialPort1.PortName = "COM" + x.ToString();
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
try
{
    if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceived);
```

Every second, a function is called, being dataToSend "abcde", for example:

```
private void DataSender(string dataToSend)
{
    serialPort1.Write(dataToSend);
    //MessageBox.Show(dataToSend);
}
```

And all of the Arduino code (I'm using a Arduino Mega which has 4 serial ports):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial3.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial3.available() > 0) {
    delay(10);
    int x = Serial3.read();
    delay(10);
    Serial.println(x);
  }
}
```

I tried adding delays to see if the data was better obtained, but it didn't work. Any ideas what I'm missing here? I assume it has something to do with the way data is encrypted to be sent, but I have no idea.

Comment: Code point of `'a'` is 97, not 79.

Comment: I know, i thought that maybe it was reversed, but the other letters don't check out either.

Comment: Assuming that you can write into your serial port from an array of bytes, try sending in `new byte[] {97, 98, 99, 100, 101}` instead of a string, and see what's going to happen.

Comment: Forget what i said before, i just tried this and... it shows the same numbers, 79 167 186 170 2. So I guess it's Arduino getting the translation wrong?

Comment: Try `Serial.write(x);` instead. Also, the delays aren't helping, you can remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds itself with the same problem as I did, my problem was that the board was overloaded. I had 6 ultrasonic sensors attached plus some other things. When I changed their power source, it started working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `Serial.println(x);` is printing as an ASCII encoded decimal, I believe this is the standard behavior for that method.

Unfortunately I can not replicate this issue at the moment, but I believe using `Serial.readString(x)` instead of `Serial.read()` may fix it.

The data is not encrypted when sent over serial, it is just sent as plaintext bytes, it is on the receiver to know how to encode them.

see: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/

From my comment below.
Also it may be worth sending the string over as a byte array `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSend);` and sending the byte array over the wire. that way there is no question as to what encoding you are using

Comment: I've tried this and the output is "O⸮⸮⸮". I meant encrypted as in bytes and not text, sorry.  I'm gonna look up and see if there are more methods to read the info though, thanks.

Comment: that makes sense since the values 79 167 186 170 2 in decimal encoded ascii are O§ºª in ascii text.

the decimal encoded ascii that would correspond to "abcde" is 97 98 99 100 101

have you tried casting the println on the arduino?

Comment: I would also suggest using a comport sniffer to see if the data is being sent over the wire is wrong, or if the arduino is encoding it wrong.

Also it may be worth sending the string over as a byte array
`byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSend);` and sending the byte array over the wire. that way there is no question as to what encoding you are using,

Comment: Do you mean something like wireshark? I've tried to use it in the past, but haven't managed to. I'll give it a try.

Comment: you wireshark does not work for comports (as far as I know) you would need a specific application for that, you can find them on google quite easily. Also I edited my comment above with a little more information.

Comment: Update: the method you mention on your second comment outputs 101 when I write "5", which is more than enough for what I want (I only need to send numbers from 1 to 9, really, so I can do translating them to binary). Thanks you so much! Could you please add this method to the response?